# can we combine "as frequent as" and "as long as"?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, grammaticality, as

it is possible to combine below two sentences in two one

*1. as frequently as someone wants to connect.
2. as long as someone wants to connect.*

can it be used -- *as frequently and long as someone wants to connect.*

By the word "connect", I'm mean long and frequent contact between people, maybe over a phone line.

Comment: I don't know if this is you exact intended context, but given the worsening Covid19 situation, perhaps *ISPs say they will continue to provide full broadband access as frequently and **for as** long as anyone wants to connect*. Maybe replace ***frequently*** by ***often***, giving the relatively common collocation [***as often and for as long as...***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22as+often+and+for+as+long+as%22)

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica -- This is exactly what I was looking for. You made my day. Thank you